# retrieve and loop all data- attributes starting with string in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

Given:

```
<a href="#" data-ajax-this="foo" data-ajax-that="faa" data-apple="tree" data-pear="pot"></a>
```

I'd like to retrieve and loop through "data-ajax-this" and "data-ajax-that" only.

I can loop all data attributes as such:

```
$.each($('a').data(), function(i,v){
  console.log(i+" , "+v);
})
```

...and I guess I could query "i" to see if it contains "ajax" within the function:

```
$.each($('a').data(), function(i,v){
  if(i.indexOf('ajax') !== -1){
    console.log(i+" , "+v);
  }
})
```

But ideally I'd like to do the selection using only .data(). Is it possible to do something like:

```
$.each($('a').data('ajax'+*), function(i,v){
  console.log(i+" , "+v);
})
```

thanks

Comment: There's no such function in jQuery (and there's no alternatives in vanilla DOM API - except filtering out `dataset`, of course, but that's basically the same as you've shown). How about using specific attribute namespace instead?

Comment: I don't think there's any shortcut for this. But you should use `indexOf() == 0` so it only matches at the beginning, not anywhere in the attribute.

Comment: Thanks both. @raina77ow could you give an example please? thank you

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't elegant and relies on nested loops you can accomplish what you're after.

You can use the `attributes` property and loop over that.

```
$.each($('a'), function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
    if ( this.name.indexOf('data-ajax') === 0 ) {
      // Do somethng with this.value
    }
  });
});
```